how to redirect the 400 error in tomcat 9 version with custom error page
i tried to redirect the 400 error with my custom error page but its not working.
400 only not redirect, 404 and 500 its working fine
1:
 <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/faces/errors.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/faces/notfound.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/faces/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

2:
changed in server level --sever.xml file its also not working
 <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

                     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       errorCode.400="/faces/errors.xhtml"
       showReport="false"
       showServerInfo="false" />

3
created the servelet class to redirect the error its also not working
package tneb.ccms.consumer;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/error400")
public class Error400Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Set response content type
        
        //System.out.println( request.getRequestURI());
         response.setContentType("text/html");

        System.out.println("error page");
        // Set response status to 400 Bad Request
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
       
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/faces/errors.xhtml");
       
    }
}

package tneb.ccms.consumer;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BadRequestFilter implements Filter {

     private FilterConfig filterConfig;

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
            this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
            HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

            try {
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (httpResponse.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST) {
                    httpRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/faces/errors.xhtml").forward(request, response);
                } else {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
            // Cleanup code if needed
        }
}

i tried everything i can and refer the documentation still i cant resolve this issue
if i encounter the 400 error in url it should not return the custom error page it shows normal tomcat page


http://localhost:11779/tangedco-public/%



404:
http://localhost:11779/tangedco-public/~ --its encounter the 404 error its working fine and shows the custom error page
output:
404 -The page you are trying to access is not found.
ZZZZZ - The requested resource could not be found on this server.
I tried everything i know,created the standalone project and set the custom error and upgrade and downgraded the tomcatversion still i cant resolve the error!

Project Tree
hello-tomcat9-web
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── HelloStatusServlet.java
        └── webapp
            ├── 400.html
            ├── 404.html
            ├── 500.html
            ├── index.jsp
            └── WEB-INF
                └── web.xml

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloweb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>helloweb</name>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

web.xml
Just set the corresponding web pages in web.xml - status code 400, 404, 500.
Please confirm the version of web.xml.
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
...
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>hello-tomcat9-web</display-name>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>400</error-code>
        <location>/400.html</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.html</location>
    </error-page>
    
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/500.html</location>
    </error-page>
           
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>  
</web-app>

HelloStatusServlet.java
HelloStatusServlet can be used to simulate generating and returning 400 and 500 status codes.
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/helloStatus")
public class HelloStatusServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String errorType = request.getParameter("error");

        if ("400".equals(errorType)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Simulated 400 Error");
            return;
        } else if ("500".equals(errorType)) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Simulated 500 Error");
            return;
        }

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello, World!</h1><p/>");
        out.println("<h1>Status TEST!</h1><p/>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
}

index.jsp
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <p>Current Date and Time: <%= new java.util.Date() %></p>
</body>
</html>

400.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>400 - Bad Request</h1>
<p>ZZZZZ - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.</p>
</body>
</html>

404.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>404 - Page Not Found</h1>
<p>ZZZZZ - The requested resource could not be found on this server.</p>
</body>
</html>

500.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Internal Server Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>500 - Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>ZZZZZ - Sorry, something went wrong on our end. Please try again later.</p>
</body>
</html>

Package
mvn clean package

put war to tomcat
put helloworld.war to Tomcat/webapps/
Start Tomcat
Test

http://localhost:8080/helloworld/

return index.jsp


http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloStatus

return helloStatus servlet.


http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloStatus?error=400

Simulates a status code of 400.


http://localhost:8080/helloworld/helloStatus?error=500

Simulates a status code of 500.


http://localhost:8080/helloworld/12324344

return 404

Debug More

http://localhost:8080/tangedco-public/% show tomcat HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request , not my 400 error page. FAIL.
http://localhost:8080/tangedco-public/~ show my 404 error page.

Check log
logs/catalina.out
12-Jul-2024 18:03:20.057 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters Character decoding failed. Parameter [%] with value [] has been ignored. Note that the name and value quoted here may be corrupted due to the failed decoding. Use debug level logging to see the original, non-corrupted values.
 Note: further occurrences of Parameter errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

change server.xml
add URIEncoding="UTF-8"
<!--
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
-->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               />    

same problem. not solve URI invalid character problem.
add config file
conf/logging.properties
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.level = FINE
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.level = FINE

shutdown tomcat
start tomcat
test again

http://localhost:8080/tangedco-public/% show tomcat HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request , not my 400 error page. FAIL.
http://localhost:8080/tangedco-public/~ show my 404 error page.

Check log again
logs/catalina.out
12-Jul-2024 18:23:59.711 XXXX [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.processParameters Character decoding failed. Parameter [%] with value [null] has been ignored.
    org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder$DecodeException: End of file (EOF)
12-Jul-2024 18:24:30.096 XXXX [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service Error parsing HTTP request header
    java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1343)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1231)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:936)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
12-Jul-2024 18:24:30.098 XXXX [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request
    java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1343)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1231)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:789)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:348)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:936)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

My inference is that when the request comes in, it will be processed first in org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service, but when illegal characters are found, it will cause it to generate an org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.setErrorState Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request, leading to early termination and not sending the request to the scope of our own webapp level. In other words, our webapp has not received the request at all and has been sent to the tomcat server level in advance. Disposed of.
As for how to deal with this problem, this is a problem of how Tomcat handles illegal characters in URIs, so we need to seek answers to how Tomcat handles illegal characters.

Thanks for your response -_-
i was check and changed as per your advice in my case i was using xhtml and
@WebServlet("/errorStatus")
public class ErrorServlet extends HttpServlet {
url:http://localhost:11779/tangedco-public/errorStatus?error=400
ouput:
400 Error
ZZZZZ - The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.
Please click here to login again..
if i encounter the 400 by symbol url:http://localhost:11779/tangedco-public/%
got the default tomcat error page
404 error by symbol url:http://localhost:11779/tangedco-public/~
its work custom page

(1) You can see my example. I don’t use any other Filter or Servlet. I only need to set the error-page of web.xml. (2) The only servlet is used to simulate the status code of Server throwing error 400. Let the server redirect 400.html based on error 400. This servlet is not responsible for redirection, it just simulates throwing error 400 if there is an error in the back-end program. (3) Another thing to note is that if you use @WebServlet("/errorStatus"), do not set this servlet in web.xml.

yes got it , but my case it different we have security adit so i want redirect the error with custom error pages.how can i get that default methods its not working if you know any solution kindly let me know give me any id to discuss about issue! -_-

My suggestion to you is to build the simplest webapp without putting too many things, just like the example I provided, and see if you can test the results you want. If it has the least content, it can be completed. It means that you originally The webapp has redundant and unnecessary settings that cause it to fail.

Remember to check the version in your web.xml. I use 3.1, you should check your version.

yes the same version i also tried in my web.xml.created the standlone and tested it also not working out!can you try in ur project add-% in url and encountered the 400 error ! check whether its working or not.

when i encounter the 400 error -% in url .in my console got this msg
Jul 12, 2024 12:03:10 PM org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve sendErrorPage
WARNING: Unable to find a static error page at [/tangedco-public/WebContent/errors.xhtml]

@Ganesh Kumar - I updated the answer to explain the results of the test and possible reasons for this result. Basically, the URI contains illegal characters. The next question is, how do you deal with illegal characters.

thx for your time and effort, i tried every thing in every angle but no luck let see...
